# Files array is NULL when uploading picture

Tags: php, image, file

I have a simple form

```
<form method="post" action="editownpage.php" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">xxx</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> <br>

    <label for="uplCss">xxx.</label>
    <textarea id="uplCss" name="uplCss"> <?php echo $css; ?></textarea> <br>

    <input type="submit" name="uplSubmit" id="uplSubmit" value="Hochladen">
</form>
```

The textarea field works like a charm, but I want to let the user upload a image. But when I do this `var_dump($_FILES['file']);` it is always `null`. No image can be processed ? What can be the reasons ? The max. file size in the php.ini is set to 3mb. The images I'm uploading are 70kb.

Comment: Have you checked the `post_max_size`? This has to exceed the max file size

Answer (score 3):

You're missing your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag. Without it the file will not upload.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="editownpage.php" id="uploadForm">
```

Comment: Hi. Just added it, still NULL. Updated the initial post for my current form

Answer (score 1):

Also your var_dump ( $_FILES['file] ); should be:

```
var_dump ( $_FILES['file'] );
```

You are missing off the '

Comment: Please just edit your existing answer instead of adding new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
var_dump ( $_FILES['file] );
```

You are missing the closing quote.

Use `$_FILES['file'];`

Read this documentation about how to access the file properties. it can be helpful for you

[PHP File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in your form tag

See this example as to why it is important.

[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Drat! someone beat me to answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this without giving the index name. Its working at my side.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

or use.

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'].'<br />';
echo $_FILES['file']['type'].'<br />';
echo $_FILES['file']['size'].'<br />';
```